# Is there a way to distinguish between public and private property with MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocation, privacy

I've been toying around with an AR-based game, but I wanted to avoid the Pokemon Go problem of people going into private property to play the game, as well as limiting the scope of the problem where someone might choose their own home or office as a "home base" for the game and potentially get real-world harassment at one of those places.

My thought was that maybe there is some way to distinguish between public and private property using MapKit metadata, e.g. look at whether a particular spot is on a street or a sidewalk or a public park, and limit access to anything that's not clearly public.

CLGeocoder, which returns CLPlacemark, seems really close, but while it clearly tells you the street you're on at a given lat/long, and what waterway you're near, it doesn't look like I can ask if the place where a user is standing is a street, a park, or somewhere in their home or office or something like that.

Considering Apple's own maps can display that information, and considering transit / directions must be able to access that sort of metadata, I'd hope that it'd be possible out of the box to do this, but it appears not to be. Anyone had luck with this, or with using any sort of third party product to do the same thing?

Comment: When I saw `swift` tag with "public and private property" title, I assumed you were going to be asking about Swift access levels associated with properties of some Swift class. I wasn't expecting a question about real-estate. Lol. Regarding your question, no, I don't know of any API that captures this...

Comment: Haha, yeah, that was the kind of answer I came up with on most of my searches. But it seems like something that should be available. Or at least you should be able ask if a location.isOnAStreet or location.isInAPark. Maybe I'll open a radar if I don't get an answer.